# syncing sqlite3 for Django tutorial

Tags: django, sqlite, syncdb, manage.py

I'm starting the Django tutorials and have virtual environments and django installed. I'm working on a Mac 10.6.8, which has sqlite3 already installed.

I'm working inside a virtual environment. I changed the settings.py file to:

```
ENGINE -- 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
```

I left the `NAME` -- in the settings.py file blank (i.e. `''`) because the tutorial said

> "If the file doesn't exist, it will automatically be created when you synchronize the database for the first time."

But when I run `python manage.py syncdb`, I get the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Please fill out the database NAME in the settings module before using the database.

Why isn't my file automatically created? Or what do I need to do to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be created for you, but [you have to specify what name to call it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) so just set `NAME` to `sqlite.db` or something similar. You can also specify a path so that it doesn't clog up your project directory. I usually save the dev database outside of my project.

Comment: Cool. Thanks Timmy. That worked. Just one follow-up question: If I save the path outside the project directory, will I still have access to it when I'm in the virtual environment? (I'm imagining the virtual environment like a sandbox around my project. I can play with the things I put into the sandbox.) So when I place a file outside of that, can I still access it when my virtual environment is active?